# Probability that common $k$ elements

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

Let $U = \lbrace 1, 2, \dotsc, K \rbrace$. Now we take all possible subsets of $U$ of contiguous numbers except the null set and arrange them in $K$ tiers based on the number of elements in them. For example, for $U = \lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4 \rbrace$, we have $4$ tiers as follows:

$T_1: \lbrace 1 \rbrace, \lbrace 2 \rbrace, \lbrace 3 \rbrace$, $\lbrace 4 \rbrace$

$T_2: \lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace, \lbrace 2, 3 \rbrace, \lbrace 3, 4 \rbrace$

$T_3: \lbrace 1, 2, 3 \rbrace$, $\lbrace 2, 3, 4 \rbrace$

$T_4: \lbrace 1, 2, 3, 4\rbrace$,

where index $i$ ($1 \leq i \leq K$) of $T_i$ denotes the number of elements of the sets that are in $T_i$.

Now, suppose Alice chooses set randomly in $T_i$ and Bob we chooses a set randomly in $T_j$ ($1 \leq i \leq K$), what is the probability that there are exactly $k$ elements common between the randomly chosen set in $T_j$ by Bob and the randomly chosen set in $T_i$ by Alice?

For example, for the test set $\lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace \in T_2$,  $\lbrace 1 \rbrace$ and $\lbrace 2 \rbrace$ in $T_1$ have one element in common with $\lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace$. Similarly, the set $\lbrace 1, 2, 3 \rbrace$ in $T_3$ has two elements common with $\lbrace 1, 2 \rbrace$.

EDIT: I earlier accepted the first answer. Later I realized that for $k = i = j$, the expression yields the answer which twice the correct answer. For the special case, $K = k = i = j$, where Alice and Bob have exactly the same number, the probability is $2$!

Answer (score 2):

Assume wlog that $k\leq i\leq j$. We define $m,n\in\{1,...,K\}$ such that Alice's set is given by $A=\{m,...,m+i-1\}$ and $B=\{n,...,n+j-1\}$ is Bob's set. Note that $m\in\{1,...,K-i+1\}$ and $n\in\{1,...,K-j+1\}$ giving us $(K-i+1)(K-j+1)$ options for sets chosen. $A$ and $B$ share exactly $k$ elements if $n-m=i-k$ or $i-k=m+i-1-n-j+1=m-n+i-j$.

We have that $n-m=i-k$ for $n\in\{i-k+1,...,K-j+1\}$ and $m=n-i+k$, i.e. in $$K-j+1-i+k=K+k-i-j+1$$ cases.

We have that $i-k=m-n+i-j$ for $n\in\{1,...,K+k-j-i+1\}$ and $m=n+j-1+i-k$, i.e. in $$K+k-j-i+1=K+k-i-j+1$$ cases. (As we would expect due to symmetry.) Hence the probability is given by
$$P(k\text{ common elements})=2\frac{K+k-i-j+1}{(K-i+1)(K-j+1)}$$
if $i-k<K-j+1$ and the probability is $0$ if $i-k\geq K-j+1$.

Comment: I just realized that when $K = i =j = k$, the probability that $k$ elements are common is $2$ according to the expression. Did I miss something?